# A simple Liquid CamelCase does not do its job

Tags: liquid

A simple *CamelCase* conversion does not seem to work at our end.

This is the example from Shopify that is supposed to return `ComingSoon`.

```
{{ 'coming-soon' | camelcase }}
```

We are not using Shopify but the tool supports Liquid and we have done other Liquid work with it.

But the code above does not alter the text and returns `coming-soon`.

**UPDATE:**
I am trying the code [in an online sandbox](https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/) but it gives me the same results. So now I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `camelcase` or `camelize` filter is Shopify only unfortunately. See this Github bug report:

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/755

**Edit:**

If you wanted to mimic this in Shopify you could do something like:

```
{%- assign input = 'long-camel-case-string' -%}
{%- assign parts = input | replace: ' ', '-' | split: '-' -%}
{%- capture camel -%}
    {%- for part in parts -%}
        {%- if forloop.index == 1 -%}
            {{ part }}
        {%- else -%}
            {{ part | capitalize }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
 {%- endcapture -%}
 {{ camel }}
```

If you were going to use this regularly you could put it all in a snippet, then use another capture to grab it, eg:

```
{%- capture output -%}{%- render 'camelize', input: 'long-camel-case-string' -%}{%- endcapture -%}
{{ output }}
```

Comment: I see. You are right. Is there a way to do this in Liquid without requiring extensions?

Comment: @disasterkid - just added some more info with a solution for Shopify

Comment: Sorry, but do these codes apply to Shopify or normal Liquid? We are not using Shopify.

Comment: The first part is general liquid and should work - the second part with the render won't work. You can test it here: https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/

Comment: Thank you so much! You can specify that the first snippet works outside of Shopify as well.

Comment: One small thing, my Liquid tags did not work with the dash in `{%-`. I had to change them to `{%`.

Comment: Ah ok, that must be a Shopify thing, it removes extra white space.